# Shouldn't set SoLinger to false cut this connection?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, so-linger

From what I understand, linger is a setting allowing to keep the connection some delay after close for the final data to have time to be read.

I have this example:

```
@Ignore
public class SocketTTest
{
    @Test
    public void socketTest() throws Throwable
    {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try
            {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5555);

                while(true)
                {

                    //keep listening
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    socket.setSoLinger(false, 0);

                    InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();

                    System.out.println(in.read());

                    Thread.sleep(2000);

                    System.out.println(in.read());

                    in.close();
                    socket.close();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
            catch(Throwable ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();

        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 5555);
        socket.setSoLinger(false, 0);
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        out.write(1);
        out.write(2);
        out.close();
        socket.close();

        synchronized(this)
        {
            wait();
        }
    }
}
```

And the output

```
1 
2
```

How does the 2 is read? The linger is disabled, the socket shouldn't be in a unreadable state when coming out of sleep?

Comment: Side note: both `in.close()` and `out.close()` will close the socket, so `socket.close()` is not needed after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't `setSoLinger()` to `false` cut this connection?

No.

> From what I understand, linger is a setting allowing to keep the connection some delay after close for the final data to have time to be read.

No. TCP already does that by default. It is a setting that causes `close()` to block for a specified timeout while there is still pending data waiting to be sent. There is little point in setting it, and all that your code has accomplished by calling `setSoLinger(false, 0)` is to reassert the default setting. Your code will work equally well without it, and with or without the sleeps.

SO_LINGER can also be used to abuse TCP/IP by resetting the connection, but you aren't doing that here.

> How the 2 is read?

Because TCP doesn't lose data in this way.

> The linger is disabled

True, but it already was, see above.

> the socket shouldn't be in an unreadable state when it comes out of sleep?

I don't know what this means. Either you're contradicting yourself or there is an inadvertent double negative here.